# Why doesn't prettier allow me to break the function arguments into multiline?

Tags: javascript, prettier

Prettier automatically changes

```js
    it(
      "Throws error if item has source: false and doesn't have children",
      () => {
        const rawData = [{ slug: 'item-name', source: false }]

        jest.doMock('../sidebar.json', () => rawData)

        expect(() => require('./helper')).toThrow(
          new Error(
            "If you set 'source' to false, you had to add at least one child"
          )
        )
      }
    )
```

to this

```js
    it("Throws error if item has source: false and doesn't have children", () => {
      const rawData = [{ slug: 'item-name', source: false }]

      jest.doMock('../sidebar.json', () => rawData)

      expect(() => require('./helper')).toThrow(
        new Error(
          "If you set 'source' to false, you had to add at least one child"
        )
      )
    })
```

My prettier configuration:

```
semi: false
singleQuote: true
trailingComma: none
printWidth: 80
tabWidth: 2
useTabs: false
proseWrap: always
```

It somehow doesn't respect the `printWidth` rule and writes all the arguments into one line.

My current workaround is `// prettier-ignore` but is there a better solution?

Comment: That's because the line width is 78, by the looks, so it is respecting the rule  :P Try reducing it to 75 and see if that has any effect?

Comment: @Kobe Oh really sorry for the wrong formatting. But I have edited it now. Please note the extra indentation added since it is already inside a function `describe('default', () => { /* 'it' is here */ })` which is indented by two spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Prettier treats test framework function calls differently to other function calls, forcing them all onto the same line.

[source](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/ae176f2e790bb61144eb071acc1c22616fe1401e/src/language-js/print/call-expression.js#L39)